# Explained Sums of Squares in matrix notation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, matrix

I am currently reading Appendix C from Gujarati Basic Econometrics 5e.
It deals with the Matrix Approach to Linear Regression Model.

I am unable to decipher how the author went from equation 7.4.19 to C.3.17

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In short, the author is not going from 7.4.19 to C.3.17.

C.3.17 is just a definition, from which we can construct 7.4.19.

The total sum of squares in pure matrix form is the following:
\begin{align}
y^TM_{\iota}y = y^T(I - \iota(\iota^T\iota)^{-1}\iota^T)y = y^Ty - n\bar{y}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{y})^2
\end{align}

Where $M_{\iota}$ is a orthogonal projection matrix and $\iota$ is a column of ones and $I$ is the identity matrix of size $n$.

The Explained Sum of Squares is defined in C.3.17, but I will start from a more familiar definition so it makes more sense how the author ended up there.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y})^2 &= \hat{y}^TM_{\iota}\hat{y}\\
& = (X\hat{\beta})^TM_{\iota}(X\hat{\beta})\\
& = \hat{B^T}X^T(I - \iota(\iota^T\iota)^{-1}\iota^T)X\hat{\beta}\\
& = \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}^TX^T\iota(\iota^T\iota)^{-1}\iota^TX\hat{\beta}\\
& = \hat{\beta}^TX^TX((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty) - n\bar{\hat{y}^2}\\
& = \hat{\beta}^TX^Ty - n\bar{y}^2
\end{align}

Edit: Was missing $X^T$ in final line

Comment: This has confused me more....

Comment: Is it the matrix notation that is difficult to follow and general matrix operations or is it the steps I make between lines. If it's the former I can try and relate things more explicitly to notation you are familiar with and maybe comment on some basic matrix operations. If it is the later, please let me know which steps and I will clarify

Comment: It's the former.